# Right join without intersection and another condition

Tags: sql, join

I want to do a right join like this:

[image]

I want all B without any A 
OR
All B with *just* A.type <> 0 (if they have a single A.type = 0 i don't want them)

For now I have this :

```
SELECT B.* 
FROM A 
RIGHT JOIN B ON A.ticket = B.id 
WHERE A.id IS NULL
  AND B.state NOT IN (3,4,10)
  AND B.disable = 0
```

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are using.

Comment: try adding `AND A.type <> 0` to your where

Comment: Can you explain why you want RIGHT JOIN here? It's like `select only optional data from optional data right join main table`...

Comment: If i add A.type <> 0 the query returns nothing.
B table = thread table, A table = message table. I need to know if a thread doesn't have any messages (so no entry in table A) or if it doesn't have any text messages (type = 0)

Comment: https://blog.jooq.org/2016/07/05/say-no-to-venn-diagrams-when-explaining-joins/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no reason to use `RIGHT JOIN`.  For most people, it is simply more confusing than `LEFT JOIN` for two reasons.  First, the `FROM` clause is read "left to right".  A `LEFT JOIN` keeps all rows in the first table in the clause.  The `RIGHT JOIN` in the not-yet-seen last table.  Second, the `FROM` clause is parsed left-to-right, which introduces some subtle issues when combining multiple outer joins.

Next, you explicitly say:

> i want to exclude B who doesn't have a A.Type = 0

This is equivalent to:

> i want to include B who have no A.Type = 0

This is not quite an outer join.  I think this is closer to what you want:

In your case:

```
SELECT  B.*
FROM B
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM A
                  WHERE A.ticket = B.id AND A.Type = 0
                 ) AND
      B.state NOT IN (3, 4, 10) AND B.disable = 0;
```

Comment: What you said is true, i want B who haven't A or A.type = 0. Concerning your query, i get some B with A or A.type = 0 and if i change A.Type = 0 to A.Type <> 0 i got same result than my first query. But thanks

Comment: If you want `B` with no `A`, then the condition on `A.type` is irrelevant.  There should be no matching row.  If that is what you want then remove `A.Type = 0` from the subquery.

Comment: I want B with no A OR B who just have A.type <> 0 (if they have just 1 A.type = 0 i don't want them) @Gordon Linoff

Comment: @Philigane . . . That is exactly the logic that this implements, subject to the additional conditions on `B`.

Comment: Well i have to apologize your first query returns all B without any A or all B with just `A.Type <> 0` (i did a confusion in my A-B conversion). Is it possible to have this result with a join and not 2 selects ? (message to upvote) @Gordon Linoff

Answer (score 1):

You want B, where if there is any value in A elated to B, it's type <> 0, so:

```
SELECT * FROM B
WHERE B.id NOT IN (
   SELECT ticket  FORM A
   WHERE A.type = 0 )
```

---

**NOT Acceptable**

<s>*May be you want some thing like this:*</s>

```
SELECT  B.* FROM A 
RIGHT JOIN B
ON A.ticket = B.id 
WHERE
     A.type<>0
 -- (A.id is null OR A.type<>0)
 -- A.id IS NULL
 -- AND A.type <> 0 -- added for exclude a.type = 0
 AND B.state NOT IN (3,4,10)
 AND B.disable = 0
```

It means `JOIN`ing where `A.type` is not `0` and other conditions that you planned for your query

Comment: That don't do what i need (but thanks).  B table = thread table, A table = message table. I need to know if a thread doesn't have any messages (so no entry in table A) or if it doesn't have any text messages (type = 0, other type are allowed)

Comment: So `(A.id is null OR A.type<>0)` can be useful ? @Philigane

Comment: No, it should be if i'm logic but i get some threads with messages (because their id isn't null) @MohaMad

Comment: If `A.type<>0` yield to nothing, it means there is no messages OR there is some text messages. can we change `(..)` to just `A.type<>0` ? @Philigane

Comment: If i just put `A.type <> 0`, i get some threads with text messages because you can possibly have some text messages and other messages in the same thread (forget to mention that, my bad). @MohaMad

Comment: B.id is not in list of tickets that `A.type = 0` , one code block added to my answer, does it helps? @Philigane

Comment: yes that does the job after those 2 requests i have to join arrays. Even if i would a single request those 2 do what i need. Same as Gordon, thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can have the desired result with a join instead of a subquery in this way:

```
select  B.id
from    A right join B on A.ticket = B.id
where   B.state not in (3, 4, 10) and B.disable = 0
group by B.id
having count(case when A.ticket is not null and A.type = 0 then 1 end) = 0;
```

This way you're only taking into account the rows of B that either don't have any matching row in A or have some but none with `A.type = 0`.

---

**Wrong pre-edit answer**

I'd go with:

```
select  B.*
from    A right join B on A.ticket = B.id
where   B.state not in (3, 4, 10) and B.disable = 0 and coalesce(A.type, 1) <> 0
```

This way you only take into account the rows that either don't join or join but don't have `A.type = 0`.

Note that depending on the database you're using, the `coalesce` function might have to be replaced with something equivalent.

Comment: It doesn't do what i need, i get some threads with messages (same result than @MohaMad). But thanks

Answer (score 0):

Using subqueries to achieve the same query and keeping the RIGHT JOIN. This method may also be faster as it tries to join the minimal amount of records from the tables on the two JOIN sides.

```
SELECT B2.* 
FROM 
  (SELECT ticket, type FROM A WHERE type=0) A2 
RIGHT JOIN 
  (SELECT * FROM B WHERE B.state NOT IN (3,4,10) AND B.disable = 0) B2 
ON A2.ticket = B2.id WHERE A2.ticket IS NULL;
```

Comment: A = A2 and B = B2 (same table name) ? @Dan Getz

Comment: subquery tables need names. A2 != A for example, it has only rows with `type=0`. The A2 and B2 need to have `AS` before them, but it is optional IIRC

Comment: Fixed a small type (`A2.id` instead of `A2.ticket` in `WHERE` clause). It works in a simulated sandbox of MySQL

Comment: This means i have to extract all type = 0 in another table ? I prefer avoid that kind of method but thanks anyway @Dan Getz

Comment: This should return all the B records you wanted i.e. either with no A or with A records but only with type<>0. Have you tried running the query?